# Why does this code get 'port already in use' errors?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (1 == argc) {  // if nothing go in 
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-0);
    }

    int port = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10); //pass
    if (0 == port) {
        perror("Invalid port");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &handle_sigchld;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Unable to register sigaction");
        exit(-2);
    }

    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (-1 == s) {
        perror("Unable to create server socket");
        exit(-3);
    }

    int optval = 1;
    if (0 != setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval))) {
        perror("Unable to setsockopt");
        exit(-4);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in bind_addr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port = htons(port)
    };

    if (0 != bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &bind_addr, sizeof(bind_addr))) {
        perror("Unable to bind socket");
        exit(-5);
    }

    if (0 != listen(s, 10)) {
        perror("Unable to listen");
        exit(-6);
    }

    while (1) {
        int s_ = accept(s, NULL, NULL); 

        sleep(BRUTE_FORCE_TIMEOUT); //here is the stop !!!(but after I delete this, it still stops but in the first line of this while loop)

        if (-1 == s_) {
            perror("Unable to accept");
            continue;
        }

        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if (-1 == child_pid) {
            perror("Unable to fork");
            goto accept_cleanup;
        }

        if (0 == child_pid) {
            close(s);
            handle(s_);
            exit(0);
        }

accept_cleanup:
        close(s_);
    }

    exit(0);
}

void handle(int s)
{
    char inbuf[4096];
    dup2(s, 0);
    dup2(s, 1);
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    alarm(ALARM_TIMEOUT_SEC);
    printf("crackme> ");
    if (NULL == fgets(inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), stdin))
    {
        return;
    }
    right_trim(inbuf);
    if(is_correct(inbuf))
    {
        printf("Good job!\n");
    }
}
```

To run this program, I need to run the name of the program plus port number. 
For example:

```
./my_file 6000
```

The problem is when I run it with the port already running, I get an error that the port is already in use.
If I try to run it with port 0, I get an error that the Port Invalid: success.
If I run it with just a random port, Linux descending line and nothing happens.

When I debug this in gdb, it stops on the `sleep` line, so I delete this line but then it stops again, but now on the first line of the while loop (`while (1) { int s_ = ...`).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you saying that the two error conditions (a) the port is already in-use, or (b) the port is invalid, are the problem because.... they're error conditions? Sorry, but that doesn't make much sense. "My program reports errors because of these error conditions when it runs..." ??? You know how TCP/IP works.. right?

Comment: You can't have two sockets bound to the same address (IP-address/port pair).

Comment: where in my program i use two socket that bound to the same address?

Comment: And no I wrote this software , I try to understand this program someone else wrote it

Comment: Note that `exit(-0);` is the same as `exit(0);` on any machine you're likely to be using.  You have a stray `}netinet` just after the `socket()` call; that must be a typo in the question as the code wouldn't compile otherwise (please confirm by editing the question to remove that — or otherwise fixing the code so it matches what you're compiling).  The choice of `s` and `s_` as variable names is perhaps not all that good.  What are you using to connect to this program when it is running?  Have you ensured that all previous copies are not still running?  What does the `handle()` function do?

Comment: Note that the `accept()` call (the first line in the `while (1)` loop), won't return until some process connects to the port that the program is listening to.  I don't understand what you mean when you say "If I run it with just a random port, Linux descending line and nothing happens".  Can you rewrite that from "Linux descending" onwards?

Comment: Linux just start to wait to somthing

Comment: All your descriptions of the program's behavior -- in the question, in the code, and among these comments -- seem perfectly reasonable.  What is the actual problem?  How does the observed behavior differ from your expectations?

Comment: i try to get to the handle and i get stocked long befor (in the brgining of the wile loop ) i dont understand how do i pass this ... (i run the program on a remote linux server , i can use pyhon , gdb , gcc only )

Comment: Raise your hand if you have any clue what is being asked

Comment: Please note that I've added the code for `handle()` to the question — which is what you should have done.  Please explain how you are connecting to your program, and what messages you are sending.  Are you using `telnet`, or `netcat` or something else?  Unless something connects to your program, it will hang in the `accept()` call — that's the job of the `accept()` call.  And you've not told us anything about how you are making that connection.

Comment: i make the conaction with netcat , and thank to you all i secceed to  make  connection , i didnt realize that the program heng at the accept() call , after i understud this i secceded to connect to the softwere with no problem ,thank you all and aspaciali   Jonathan Leffler